# Two functions can run concurrently but not with other functions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have ten generic functions which all run frequently in my framework. Two of these functions are of type A, and the other eight are of type B. I want to be able to run the type A functions concurrently, but not allow the type B functions to run when the type A functions are running. Likewise, if a type B function is running, I don't want any type A function to be allowed to run. I also don't want any other type B running if one is already running.

Is there any better way to implement this (in Java specifically) other than using a ReentrantReadWriteLock, with the read locks around type A and the write locks around type B?

ReentrantReadWriteLock is for when a reader lock is needed most of the time, and a writer lock is needed "once in a while". However, in my case, all of the functions are used all of the time, meaning that the functions are all called at the same frequency. Whether I make the ReentrantReadWriteLock fair or unfair, I am seeing a lot of contention of the locks in my system.

Comment: If `ReentrantReadWriteLock` fits for your purpose, why do you search anything else? Unlikely there is another mechanism in Java, which has the same behavior as `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. If you think that rw-lock doesn't reflect nature of correlation between A and B, then provide more info about these functions (e.g., **why** they cannot be run concurrently).

Comment: Why are you looking for a "better" way? What is wrong with using a `ReadWriteLock`? What are you trying to "fix"? Is it simply that you don't like the names, e.g. would it be better for you if they were called Exclusive locks and Shared locks?

Comment: See edits for some more elaboration

Comment: Can many B methods run concurrently?

Comment: Great question - edited the question to improve

Comment: *I also don't want any other type B running if one is already running.* Then I'm pretty sure a read/write lock is the correct solution. The fact that you're seeing contention is more a problem in the scenario than in the solution.

Comment: "ReentrantReadWriteLocks can be used to improve concurrency in some uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that outweighs synchronization overhead. " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html
I was looking for a better implementation.

Comment: *However, in my case, all of the functions are used all of the time.* That's an impossible requirement if you're looking for mutual exclusion. If you're trying to say that the read/write *ratio* is problematic, please elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ReentrantReadWriteLock is for when a reader lock is needed most of the time, and a writer lock is needed "once in a while".

I'm not sure where you got this idea.  `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is used in many places to handle *exactly* the situation that you outline.  It is designed to be high performance and (of course) reentrant and any solution that you might cobble together from manual coding is most likely not to perform as well.

> However, in my case, all of the functions are used all of the time, meaning that the functions are all called at the same frequency.

This should be fine.  You should read the fine print of the [`ReentrantReadWriteLock` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) around "fairness" but any frequency of A and B will be handled by the lock well.

To summary the docs, in "fair" mode, if a B task goes to get the write lock, it will block *behind* a group of A tasks that are already waiting.  If an A task goes to lock then it will be allowed to run only if no B tasks are already waiting.  "Unfair" mode would allow A tasks to run and possible starve B tasks if they come continuously but may "will normally have higher throughput than a fair lock".

I would stick with "fair" policy unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise.

> Whether I make the ReentrantReadWriteLock fair or unfair, I am seeing a lot of contention of the locks in my system.

I think this is to be expected.  No matter what solution that you come up with, if you have have A and B tasks executing at a descent frequency, you will get lock contention.  Maybe if you edited your question and provided more details about why you think the contention is unexpected, we can provide better answers.

> I want to be able to run the type A functions concurrently, but not allow the type B functions to run when the type A functions are running.

So A tasks would use the *read* portion of the  `ReentrantReadWriteLock`:

```
private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
private final Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
...
private void functionA() {
    readLock.lock();
    try {
       // do the A processing here ...
    } finally {
       readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

> if a type B function is running, I don't want any type A function to be allowed to run. I also don't want any other type B running if one is already running.

So B tasks would use the write portion of the lock:

```
private void functionB() {
    writeLock.lock();
    try {
       // do the B processing here ...
    } finally {
       writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to note that the reason I was looking for a better solution is that in the docs here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html it says "ReentrantReadWriteLocks can be used to improve concurrency in some uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that outweighs synchronization overhead. " Thank you for explaining that the contention I was experiencing was normal.

Comment: Right @KeyanRhm.  I suspect that the statement you quote is trying to point out that by using this lock, you aren't saving yourself much from the overhead of the `synchronized` keyword.